# FFMPeg + x264 install. Pthreads not workng? "libpthread.a" errors

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, x264, libx264

Nothing I've tried so far works.

x264 is already installed.

OpenSSL and FDKaac are also installed.

Configure line for FFMPeg:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg/lib" --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-openssl --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-nonfree --enable-libmp3lame
```

This is an old version of FFMPeg (version ffmpeg-1.0.10). Upgrading is not possible on this machine.

This is strange because installation has worked in the past, but of course I don't remember what version was working; it was deleted and needs to be reinstalled.

The error message during compilation of ffmpeg-1.0.10 is this:

```
HOSTLD  doc/print_options
GENTEXI doc/avoptions_format.texi
GENTEXI doc/avoptions_codec.texi
POD doc/ffmpeg.pod
POD doc/ffplay.pod
POD doc/ffprobe.pod
POD doc/ffserver.pod
MAN doc/ffmpeg.1
MAN doc/ffplay.1
MAN doc/ffprobe.1
MAN doc/ffserver.1
TXT doc/fate.txt
CC  cmdutils.o
CC  ffmpeg_opt.o
CC  ffmpeg_filter.o
CC  ffmpeg.o
ffmpeg.c:154:13: warning: ‘free_input_threads’ declared ‘static’ but never defined [-Wunused-function]
 static void free_input_threads(void);
             ^
LD  ffmpeg_g
/usr/local/lib/libpthread.a(ptw-write.o): In function `__write_nocancel':
(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/usr/local/lib/libpthread.a(ptw-write.o): In function `__write_nocancel':
(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/usr/local/lib/libpthread.a(ptw-read.o): In function `__read_nocancel':
(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/usr/local/lib/libpthread.a(ptw-read.o): In function `__read_nocancel':
(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/usr/local/lib/libpthread.a(ptw-close.o): In function `__close_nocancel':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/usr/local/lib/libpthread.a(ptw-close.o):(.text+0x4b): more undefined references to `__syscall_error' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1
```

It's also not possible to change the libpthread version or upgrade the kernel, because other software  depends on the current kernel version.

Upgrading ffmpeg and/or x264 is not possible; they return pthreads errors that are similar to the ones above.

Changing the './configure' line to include '--disable-pthreads' has no effect on the ffmpeg build outcome. The error is the same as above.

Any different ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you'll find much support for such an old version of ffmpeg.